# Apache2 server not responding with IPV4 address

Tags: apache2, ipv4

I run an apache2 web server on Ubuntu 14.04 that I use to save files from my laptop with Owncloud.

I used to be able to connect via HTTP using my external IP address (IPv4), and I used that public address to connect even from my home network.

Since few days I get no response when I try from the home network, although it still works from a cellular network, and also if just log with my laptop on my company VPN.

The strange thing is the if I use HTTP:[my public IPv6] the server responds just fine.

I disabled Ubuntu firewall and Comcast router firewall for troubleshooting, but no difference.

in my **/etc/apache2/ports.conf** I have Listen 80.

Comment: Do you mean `hppt:[my_public_ip]` or `http:[my_public_ip]`

Comment: it was a typo, I meant http otherwise I would have invented a new protocol :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you're looking for can be found at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html.

Please make sure your apache2 version matches the documentation (2.4 is current version)

Long story short, add 0.0.0.0 (or whatever IPv4 address you need) before 80:

**Listen 0.0.0.0:80**

Hope it helps,